# Is it a good practice to depend on Exception Message in Catch block?

Tags: c#, exception, c#-4.0, json.net, try-catch

```
        try
        {
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IList<IList<string>>>>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                MaxDepth = 2
            });
        }
        catch (JsonReaderException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message.StartsWith("The reader's MaxDepth", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                // Trace a message here
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

I want to catch the exception only if it is because of MaxDepth overflow. I am using ex.Message to do that. Is it a good practice to get the dependency on the library's internal message string? Is there any better way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Your risk is that the library author will change the message and break your code.  It's your decision whether or not to take that risk.

Comment: You could do `catch (JasonReaderException ex) when (ex.Message.StartsWith(...))` so you don't have to rethrow any exceptions.

Comment: @juharr what is `JasonReaderException`? :)

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ It whenever a person named Jason is illiterate. ;)

Comment: set an Error class to use in other functions! ```public static class Error{ public static string ErrorDesc {get;set;} public static int ErrorCode {get;set;} }``` in your catch you could return ```Error.ErrorCode = 500``` or do ```Error.ErrorDesc = ex.Message and Error.ErrorCode = 500``` and return the Error obj, then read that in your parent function.

Comment: In general this is a bad idea, because exception messages should be **localized**.  See [Best practices for exceptions : Include a localized string message in every exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions#include-a-localized-string-message-in-every-exception) and also [Design Guidelines Update: Exception Message Guidelines](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brada/2004/01/28/design-guidelines-update-exception-message-guidelines/): *Do localize exception messages*.